shift by frequency groups by date?
I'm trying to create a simple data cube, of one metric by many different time freqencies. Example:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

r = [{'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-04-13 00:00:00'),  'metric': 1,  'weekly_cumsum': 1,  'monthly_cumsum': 1,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 1,  'weekly_sum': 1,  'monthly_sum': 1,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': np.nan,  'prev_week_2': np.nan,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-04-14 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 1,  'monthly_cumsum': 1,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 1,  'monthly_sum': 1,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': np.nan,  'prev_week_2': np.nan,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-04-15 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 1,  'monthly_cumsum': 1,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 1,  'monthly_sum': 1,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': np.nan,  'prev_week_2': np.nan,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-04-16 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 1,  'monthly_cumsum': 1,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 1,  'monthly_sum': 1,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': np.nan,  'prev_week_2': np.nan,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-04-17 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 1,  'monthly_cumsum': 1,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 1,  'monthly_sum': 1,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': np.nan,  'prev_week_2': np.nan,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-04-18 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 1,  'monthly_cumsum': 1,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 1,  'monthly_sum': 1,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': np.nan,  'prev_week_2': np.nan,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-04-19 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 1,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 1,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': np.nan,  'prev_week_2': np.nan,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-04-20 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 1,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 1,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 1.0,  'prev_week_2': np.nan,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-04-21 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 1,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 1,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 1.0,  'prev_week_2': np.nan,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-04-22 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 1,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 1,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 1.0,  'prev_week_2': np.nan,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-04-23 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 1,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 1,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 1.0,  'prev_week_2': np.nan,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-04-24 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 1,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 1,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 1.0,  'prev_week_2': np.nan,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-04-25 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 1,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 1,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 1.0,  'prev_week_2': np.nan,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-04-26 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 1,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 1,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': np.nan,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-04-27 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 1,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 1,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 1.0,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-04-28 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 1,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 1,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 1.0,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-04-29 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 1,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 1,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 1.0,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-04-30 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 1,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 1,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 1.0,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-01 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 1.0,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-02 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 1.0,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-03 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-04 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-05 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-06 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-07 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-08 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-09 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-10 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': np.nan}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-11 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 1.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-12 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 1.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-13 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 1.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-14 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 1.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-15 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 1.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-16 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 1.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-17 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-18 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-19 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-20 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-21 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-22 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-23 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-24 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-25 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-26 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-27 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-28 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-29 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-30 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-31 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 0,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-01 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-02 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-03 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-04 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-05 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-06 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-07 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 1,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-08 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 1,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-09 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 0,  'yearly_cumsum': 1,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 1,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-10 00:00:00'),  'metric': 1,  'weekly_cumsum': 1,  'monthly_cumsum': 1,  'yearly_cumsum': 2,  'daily_sum': 1,  'weekly_sum': 1,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-11 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 1,  'monthly_cumsum': 1,  'yearly_cumsum': 2,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 1,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-12 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 1,  'monthly_cumsum': 1,  'yearly_cumsum': 2,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 1,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-13 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 1,  'monthly_cumsum': 1,  'yearly_cumsum': 2,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 1,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-14 00:00:00'),  'metric': 1,  'weekly_cumsum': 1,  'monthly_cumsum': 2,  'yearly_cumsum': 3,  'daily_sum': 1,  'weekly_sum': 4,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 1.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-15 00:00:00'),  'metric': 1,  'weekly_cumsum': 2,  'monthly_cumsum': 3,  'yearly_cumsum': 4,  'daily_sum': 1,  'weekly_sum': 4,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 1.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-16 00:00:00'),  'metric': 1,  'weekly_cumsum': 3,  'monthly_cumsum': 4,  'yearly_cumsum': 5,  'daily_sum': 1,  'weekly_sum': 4,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 1.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-17 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 3,  'monthly_cumsum': 4,  'yearly_cumsum': 5,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 4,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 1.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-18 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 3,  'monthly_cumsum': 4,  'yearly_cumsum': 5,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 4,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 1.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-19 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 3,  'monthly_cumsum': 4,  'yearly_cumsum': 5,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 4,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 1.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-20 00:00:00'),  'metric': 1,  'weekly_cumsum': 4,  'monthly_cumsum': 5,  'yearly_cumsum': 6,  'daily_sum': 1,  'weekly_sum': 4,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 1.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-21 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 5,  'yearly_cumsum': 6,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 4.0,  'prev_week_2': 1.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-22 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 5,  'yearly_cumsum': 6,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 4.0,  'prev_week_2': 1.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-23 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 5,  'yearly_cumsum': 6,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 4.0,  'prev_week_2': 1.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-24 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 5,  'yearly_cumsum': 6,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 4.0,  'prev_week_2': 1.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-25 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 5,  'yearly_cumsum': 6,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 4.0,  'prev_week_2': 1.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-26 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 5,  'yearly_cumsum': 6,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 4.0,  'prev_week_2': 1.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-27 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 5,  'yearly_cumsum': 6,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 0,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 4.0,  'prev_week_2': 1.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-28 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 5,  'yearly_cumsum': 6,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 3,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 4.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-29 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 5,  'yearly_cumsum': 6,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 3,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 4.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-30 00:00:00'),  'metric': 1,  'weekly_cumsum': 1,  'monthly_cumsum': 6,  'yearly_cumsum': 7,  'daily_sum': 1,  'weekly_sum': 3,  'monthly_sum': 6,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 4.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-01 00:00:00'),  'metric': 2,  'weekly_cumsum': 3,  'monthly_cumsum': 2,  'yearly_cumsum': 9,  'daily_sum': 2,  'weekly_sum': 3,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 4.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-02 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 3,  'monthly_cumsum': 2,  'yearly_cumsum': 9,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 3,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 4.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-03 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 3,  'monthly_cumsum': 2,  'yearly_cumsum': 9,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 3,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 4.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-04 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 3,  'monthly_cumsum': 2,  'yearly_cumsum': 9,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 3,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 0.0,  'prev_week_2': 4.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-05 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 2,  'yearly_cumsum': 9,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 4,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 3.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 1.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-06 00:00:00'),  'metric': 2,  'weekly_cumsum': 2,  'monthly_cumsum': 4,  'yearly_cumsum': 11,  'daily_sum': 2,  'weekly_sum': 4,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 3.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 1.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-07 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 2,  'monthly_cumsum': 4,  'yearly_cumsum': 11,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 4,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 3.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 1.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-08 00:00:00'),  'metric': 1,  'weekly_cumsum': 3,  'monthly_cumsum': 5,  'yearly_cumsum': 12,  'daily_sum': 1,  'weekly_sum': 4,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 3.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 1.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-09 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 3,  'monthly_cumsum': 5,  'yearly_cumsum': 12,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 4,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 3.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 1.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-10 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 3,  'monthly_cumsum': 5,  'yearly_cumsum': 12,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 4,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 3.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 1.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-11 00:00:00'),  'metric': 1,  'weekly_cumsum': 4,  'monthly_cumsum': 6,  'yearly_cumsum': 13,  'daily_sum': 1,  'weekly_sum': 4,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 3.0,  'prev_week_2': 0.0,  'prev_week_3': 1.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-12 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 6,  'yearly_cumsum': 13,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 4,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 4.0,  'prev_week_2': 3.0,  'prev_week_3': 4.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-13 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 6,  'yearly_cumsum': 13,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 4,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 4.0,  'prev_week_2': 3.0,  'prev_week_3': 4.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-14 00:00:00'),  'metric': 1,  'weekly_cumsum': 1,  'monthly_cumsum': 7,  'yearly_cumsum': 14,  'daily_sum': 1,  'weekly_sum': 4,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 4.0,  'prev_week_2': 3.0,  'prev_week_3': 4.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-15 00:00:00'),  'metric': 1,  'weekly_cumsum': 2,  'monthly_cumsum': 8,  'yearly_cumsum': 15,  'daily_sum': 1,  'weekly_sum': 4,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 4.0,  'prev_week_2': 3.0,  'prev_week_3': 4.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-16 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 2,  'monthly_cumsum': 8,  'yearly_cumsum': 15,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 4,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 4.0,  'prev_week_2': 3.0,  'prev_week_3': 4.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-17 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 2,  'monthly_cumsum': 8,  'yearly_cumsum': 15,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 4,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 4.0,  'prev_week_2': 3.0,  'prev_week_3': 4.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-18 00:00:00'),  'metric': 2,  'weekly_cumsum': 4,  'monthly_cumsum': 10,  'yearly_cumsum': 17,  'daily_sum': 2,  'weekly_sum': 4,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 4.0,  'prev_week_2': 3.0,  'prev_week_3': 4.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-19 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 10,  'yearly_cumsum': 17,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 3,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 4.0,  'prev_week_2': 4.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-20 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 0,  'monthly_cumsum': 10,  'yearly_cumsum': 17,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 3,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 4.0,  'prev_week_2': 4.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-21 00:00:00'),  'metric': 1,  'weekly_cumsum': 1,  'monthly_cumsum': 11,  'yearly_cumsum': 18,  'daily_sum': 1,  'weekly_sum': 3,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 4.0,  'prev_week_2': 4.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-22 00:00:00'),  'metric': 1,  'weekly_cumsum': 2,  'monthly_cumsum': 12,  'yearly_cumsum': 19,  'daily_sum': 1,  'weekly_sum': 3,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 4.0,  'prev_week_2': 4.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-23 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 2,  'monthly_cumsum': 12,  'yearly_cumsum': 19,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 3,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 4.0,  'prev_week_2': 4.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-24 00:00:00'),  'metric': 0,  'weekly_cumsum': 2,  'monthly_cumsum': 12,  'yearly_cumsum': 19,  'daily_sum': 0,  'weekly_sum': 3,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 4.0,  'prev_week_2': 4.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}, {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-25 00:00:00'),  'metric': 1,  'weekly_cumsum': 3,  'monthly_cumsum': 13,  'yearly_cumsum': 20,  'daily_sum': 1,  'weekly_sum': 3,  'monthly_sum': 17,  'yearly_sum': 24,  'prev_week_1': 4.0,  'prev_week_2': 4.0,  'prev_week_3': 0.0}]

tdf = tdf.set_index('Date Enrolled')

I want to add time frequencies for previous_month, and previous_year.  I would think shift would work for this:
tdf['previous_month'] = tdf['monthly_sum'].shift(periods=1, freq='ME')

However it throws ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels
Upon inspecting what is returned from shift, you can see that it actually shifted everything to last months end date and not by an increment of a month.

There has to be an easy way to do this?  Anyone have a simple solution as to how to get the previous month totals next to the last months totals?
** EDIT 1 **
I've also found odd behavior where it takes this column data:
Date Enrolled
2013-11-30      2
2013-12-01      0
2013-12-02      0
2013-12-03      0

and shifted like this:
tdf['monthly_sum'].shift(periods=1, freq='ME')

returns this:
2013-12-31      2
2013-12-31      0
2013-12-31      0

See how it shifted them all to the same month end?  WTF...

Please make a minimal reproducible pandas example. This is too much data.

Also, please don't post pictures of text. Post the text itself, formatted as code (print(df)) or as a table (print(df.to_markdown()).

tdf isn't defined in this code, but I assume it's tdf = pd.DataFrame(r)

Also, what's your desired output? e.g. what result would you expect at May 31, since April 31 doesn't exist? and where should May 31 be shifted to?

@wjandrea - I would expect it to go to the last day of the next month, not 30 days.

@wjandrea - Also, why would the 1st, 2nd, & 3rd, still go to the 31's by your logic?

"why would the 1st, 2nd, & 3rd, still go to the 31's by your logic?" - TBH, I have no idea what you mean. Just show what you want, and we can go from there.

This error happened because of duplicate indices in your data frame.
What you can do is setting index.
for instance you can do it for the 'Date Enrolled' column.
tdf.set_index('Date Enrolled', inplace=True)

later you can shift by 1 for the month.
tdf['previous_month'] = tdf['monthly_sum'].shift(1)

also by 12 for the year.

The index is actually set.  I think I removed that line from code in an example.
